# UDiD into URL: Redefinition Errors

Tags: url, redefinition

So I'm trying to pass the device's UDiD into the URL, i've noted another question on StackOverflow, however it does not seem to be working. I'm receiving a 'Redefinition of 'url', anyone can help me out?

```
NSString *udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/?udid=%@",udid];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[home loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Thanks all, any help would be appreciated.